# read from ls command, create an array to move files

Tags: external-command

I recently discovered a great way to get a list of all files in a directory, I would like to create an array off of that list to then move the files to a new destination.

Currently `:read !ls *` modify the results to fit in an array. I would like to create a command to move the files based on `{"key" filename: "value" destination}`. How can I achieve this in bash or from vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be interested by the following plugins:

- [fern](https://github.com/lambdalisue/fern.vim)
- [renamer](https://github.com/qpkorr/vim-renamer)

They both allow you to:

- Build a file list in a buffer
- Rename the files using Vim functionality (e.g. `:s//`)
- Apply the changes into the file system

Remark: I have personally tested fern.

Comment: I like buffy; will try to get a link later